# Angular - using ngFor to display data with column and row headers

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table, ngfor

I´m having problem displaying data inside the table which has column and row headers. I´m trying to make it dynamic by using *ngFor. Can you suggest how to handle *ngFor in this case?

Ts file with data:

```
export class NewScreen {
  rows = [
    'Name',
    'Surname',
    'Subjects',
    'Grade',
  ];

  data = [
    {
      student: 'Student 1',
      name: 'Alex',
      surname: 'Smith',
      subjects: ['Math','Geometry'],
      grade: ['A','B'],
    },
    {
      student: 'Student 2',
      name: 'Michael',
      surname: 'Laurent',
      subjects: ['Math','Geometry'],
      grade: ['B','C'],
    },
    {
      student: 'Student 3',
      name: 'Sophie',
      surname: 'Miller',
      subjects: ['Math','Geometry'],
      grade: ['A','A'],
    },
  ];
}
```

HTML:
I have been trying to find solution to put inside {{???}} which would result in displaying following table structure, but with no luck:[image]

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th *ngFor="let column of data">{{ column.student }}</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
         <th>{{ row }}</th>
         <td *ngFor="let value of data | keyvalue">{{ value.value[i + 1] }}</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you heard of the KeyValue pipe. https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: It allows the use of both the key and value of a object.

Comment: Hi Dahir. I have edited the code based on your suggestion, but the data in the table is not being displayed. Is my edited code above correct?

Comment: If I put ```{{ item.value }}``` only, it is displayed like this: [object Object] for each field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a simple example from the HTML and data you provided
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuzjyk

The reason `{{ item.value }}` shows `[object Object]` is because you didn't give it an identifier to pick the property of that object you wish to display.

To simplify, I updated your `rows[]` to match the keys of your data to use it directly.

```js
  rows = ['name', 'surname', 'subjects', 'grade'];
```

In the HTML I simply use that row to identify the property we wish to display. Also in `<th>` I capitalize the first alphabet of each header.

```html
   <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
       <th>{{ row.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + row.slice(1) }}</th>
       <td *ngFor="let item of data">
           {{ item[row] }} 
       </td>
   </tr>
```

Check out the stackblitz link I gave above, if you have any queries feel free to ask.

Comment: This looks amazing! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Maybe just 1 additional question - How would I manage matching identifier in case I have 2 words identifier, say ```First name```?

Comment: if the identifier comes as `First name` in the data, you can simple add  `rows = ['name', 'surname', 'subjects', 'grade', 'First Name'];` in your rows list, or that wasn't your question ?

Comment: For the attribute name inside the object of data array, I can only use camel case so then it wouldn't match with ```First Name```, but I solved it with the custom pipe :)